# How can I store a boolean matrix in MVC ASP.NET

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I need to store a boolean matrix like this:

```
        public bool[][] Schedule { get; set; }
```

It's basically a schedule that is to be applied as follows in the view: [image: schedule]

It works in the view but I can't store it properly with Entity Framework, since it doesn't even create the Tables upon a migration. How can I store it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In terms of actual storage of this information in the database, a format like the following would work:

**Type Database table (optional, with use of enum)**

```
Id    Type
1     Segunda
2     Terca
3     Quarta
4     Sexta
```

**Values Database table**

```
Id     TimeFrom    TimeTo    TypeId    Selected
1      8:00        9:00      1         1
2      8:00        9:00      2         1
3      8:00        9:00      3         1
4      8:00        9:00      4         1
5      8:00        9:00      5         1
6      9:00        10:00     1         0
7      9:00        10:00     2         0
8      9:00        10:00     3         1
9      9:00        10:00     4         0
10     9:00        10:00     5         0
11     10:00       11:00     1         1
12     10:00       11:00     2         1
13     10:00       11:00     3         1
14     10:00       11:00     4         1
15     10:00       11:00     5         1
```

The following domain objects would support this layout of storage, for example:

```
public enum TypeEnum
{
    Segunda = 1,
    Terca = 2,
    Quarta = 3,
    Sexta = 4
}

public class Type
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public TypeEnum Type { get; set; }
}

public class Schedules
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public DateTime TimeFrom { get; set; }
    public DateTime TimeTo { get; set; }
    public TypeEnum TypeId { get; set; }
    public bool Selected { get; set; }
}
```

You could extrapolate the times from and to into another table if you're storing this information for multiples users or just to normalise the data.

It should be easy to map these values to a suitable view model to be mapped back and forth from the view.

Comment: How can there be several entries in the database with the same Id? Isn't it supposed to be unique? I'm new to this so I assumed it was like SQL and you couldn't have the same ID's at all.

Comment: Sorry you're quite right, I copied and pasted and forgot to change those Id values

Comment: No problem, I'll try it when I can! I need to associate it to a House class, which also as an ID. It should be simple now. Thank you!